# Variable name inside R function

Tags: variables, local

I made this very simple function transformering R data to Stata. It works but not in the way that I want.

I would like the name of the Stata data to be **cars.dta** but the output is **x.dta**.

Please help!

```
library(foreign)

writedta <- function(x) {  
                        write.dta(x, file=paste0(wkpath, "/", "x.dta", sep = ""))  
                      }

writedta(cars)
```

Comment: What is "x.dta" in your parameters?

Comment: x is the  name of dataset.

Comment: I mean is it an output file name parameter? Seems that you pass output file name there

Comment: Yes, it is output file name.

Comment: ahd what is the question? Just replace it with *cars.dta*...

Comment: No, it is not the point. X is supose to automatically take the name of input from the function. If success, writedta(cars) should produce cars.dta, writedta(ttt) should produce ttt.dta, etc. In short, x should take name from input instead of assigning a fixed name x or cars etc.